# NodeJS Mocha doesn't pass params to function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I've got following function:

```js
export function ensurePathFormat(filePath: string, test = false) {
  console.log(test);
  if (!filePath || filePath === '') {
    if (test) {
      throw new Error('Invalid or empty path provided');
    } else {
      log.error('Invalid or empty path provided');
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

and following test case in Mocha:

```js
describe('ensurePathFormat', () => {
  it('validates file path', () => {
    expect(() => ensurePathFormat('', true)).throws('Invalid or empty path provided');
  });
});
```

Of course I've got all the imports correct etc.

My problem is, each time I try to call `ensurePathFormat` function, it's being called with no parameters passed (first one is undefined and second one defaults to `false`).

I've tried calling it outside `expect`, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export function ensurePathFormat(filePath: string, test = false) {
  console.log(test);
  if (!filePath || filePath === "") {
    if (test) {
      throw new Error("Invalid or empty path provided");
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid or empty path provided");
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ensurePathFormat } from "./";
import sinon from "sinon";

describe("ensurePathFormat", () => {
  it("validates file path", () => {
    expect(() => ensurePathFormat("", true)).throws("Invalid or empty path provided");
  });

  it("should print the error", () => {
    const errorLogSpy = sinon.stub(console, "error");
    const processExitSpy = sinon.stub(process, "exit");
    ensurePathFormat("");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(errorLogSpy, "Invalid or empty path provided");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(processExitSpy, 1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 ensurePathFormat
true
    ✓ validates file path
false
    ✓ should print the error


  2 passing (15ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                 3 |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59579387